# Tab navigation on profile screen (think Instagram profile page)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**In React Native, how can I add a tab navigation in the middle of a screen?**

[image]

So far, I have got a stack-navigator managing the overall navigation for my app. As I understand it, react-navigation has a default tab component, however that component appears to be placed at the bottom of the screen, not in the middle as desired here. I am also not clear on how to integrate it given that I already have the stack-navigator.

**Current Approach:**

Doing it manually as follows. Is there a better approach using react navigation to automatically handle click-effects and slide-in animations?

```
// set the tab-index on press
selectTab = ( index ) => {
    this.setState({
        activeIndex: index,
    })
}

// render the content for the selected tab
renderTabContent = () => {
    if( this.state.activeIndex == 1 ) {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    This is the first section
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    else if( this.state.activeIndex == 2 ) {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    This is the second section
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    else if( this.state.activeIndex == 3 ) {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>
                    This is the third section
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>this.selectTab(1)} 
                    style={[this.state.activeIndex == 1 ? { backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100 } : { backgroundColor: 'gray', width: 100, }]}
                >
                    <Text>#1</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>this.selectTab(2)} 
                    style={[this.state.activeIndex == 2 ? { backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100 } : { backgroundColor: 'gray', width: 100, }]}
                >
                    <Text>#2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() =>this.selectTab(3)} 
                    style={[this.state.activeIndex == 3 ? { backgroundColor: 'red', width: 100 } : { backgroundColor: 'gray', width: 100, }]}
                >
                    <Text>#3</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            {this.renderTabContent()}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

*PS: Are there any beginner-friendly examples of real-world(ish) apps to get an idea of how common UI patterns are implemented in React Native?*

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js These examples are pretty easy. You can use createMaterialTopTabNavigator below the Text.(In Middle)

Comment: @Ben did you end up with any solution on this

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `createBottomTabNavigator` function of `react-navigation` library:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

And then create your stackNavigator :

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home},
  Search: { screen: Search},
  History: { screen: History }
});
```

You can customize your tab appearance and behavior by following this link.

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html#customizing-the-appearance

For complete example you can refer:

> https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-tabs